# Windows Azure time based event processing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I'm am trying to design an application where a user can create a task that must be run at a certain time. To compound problems this task needs to have an associated countdown function so that at say 1 minute before the time it must "come to life" and notify the user.

This solution will be developed in .net using Windows Azure and Azure Message bus. My question is once the message/task is delivered via the bus how do I architect the solution to handle potentially thousands of independent events that must be processed with second or sub second accuracy? I can't have 1 worker role per user that would be insanely expensive ...

I was thinking of using something like Quartz.net in the backend to handle the job processing and scheduling but surely there must be a better way with Azure ...

Any guidance and assistance would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the CQRS pattern, which you could use in conjunction with setting the process datetime (not sure of the property off the top of my head) of messages that are placed on the queue.  You can then scale out with additional worker roles (not client based) to handle your load to ensure "second" accuracy.

Comment: Not sure if Azure Scheduler Service may help you. It has REST API so that you can create a new task from you application. Then the task will be triggered at the time you defined without any additional works. Then you can retrieve the execution history through API as well.

Comment: Azure Scheduler Service would be ideal except it's best execution frequency is per minute which is to slow for my needs, as well the cost and limited number of jobs per collection is a major problem.